# DC Motor Pinning the Ada Fruit Moto Shield with the Mega2560 R3

Tags: arduino-mega, adafruit, arduino-motor-shield

I picked up an [AdaFruit Motor Shield V2.3](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1438) .  The example on the site shows how to code the DC Motor connection

```
// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
// Or, create it with a different I2C address (say for stacking)
// Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(0x61); 

// Select which 'port' M1, M2, M3 or M4. In this case, M1
Adafruit_DCMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getMotor(1);
// You can also make another motor on port M2
//Adafruit_DCMotor *myOtherMotor = AFMS.getMotor(2)
```

What I'm unclear about is how to connect the shield to the mega board.  Which pin on the shield should connect to which pin on the board in order for `Motor 1` to run at that speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because an Arduino Mega2560 is pretty much and UNO with a longer rear end, try seeing the UNO in the MEGA if that makes any sense. Then just put the shield in like a normal shield that you would put on a UNO. Most UNO shields are compatible with MEGAs. Then you just use your shield like if it was on an UNO.

[image: The UNO in the MEGA]